# ASP.NET unable to bind to all interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I try to create an asp.net service; which works if I try to access it locally. But it is not possible to reach it from a remote location.

Below the code I use to instantiate the server:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;
using System.Configuration;

namespace RESTService
{
  public class Service : IDisposable
  {
    private HttpSelfHostServer server;

    public Service()
    {
      var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration($"http://*:{ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["port"]}/");
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TTS", "{controller}/{text}",
        new[] { "RESTService.Controller" });

      server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
      server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      server.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

I replaced localhost with * as described in [Web API self host - bind on all network interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598042/web-api-self-host-bind-on-all-network-interfaces). Unfortunately I get an UriFormatException with this code. How can I bind the service to all interfaces?

Comment: what is the details of your exception? and what is the value $"http://*:{ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["port"]}/ after executing it?

Comment: I would like to access the service from the external network address (192.168.0.73) as well. The value for the port is 8888

Comment: Hook to the server's IP address (`192.168.0.73`?), or simply `0.0.0.0`. `*` is not valid for `Uri` class, just like the exception says.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the hint I needed:-).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lex Li; his comment pointed me into the right direction. The following code works:

```
new HttpSelfHostConfiguration($"http://{IPAddress.Any}:{ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["port"]}/")
```