# Difference between http://+:8080/ and http://*:8080/

Tags: prefix, httplistener, http.sys

What are the differences between these two prefixes in terms of `HttpListener` or any other?

```
http://+:8080/

http://*:8080/
```

Comment: How is this related to ASp.NET in any way given that this is http.sys in the kernel that takes and handles those?

Comment: Some people from Microsoft misunderstood that it is under ASP.NET and they by mistake mentioned it in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Comment: Still not Asp.net, you know. System.Net is the network part (not asp.net specific) and they clearly state this goes to http.sys. Try reading more than one line and understanding it, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between http://\*:80 and http://+:80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598164/whats-the-difference-between-http-80-and-http-80)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`http://*:8080/`: Receive all HTTP requests on port 8080 that are *not* already being handled by some other `HttpListener`.

`http://+:8080/`: Receive all HTTP requests on port 8080 *even* if they're already handled by another `HttpListener`.

Comment: will like you explain it with an example or with link ? whatever you like

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) is not very clear in this detail.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Paulpro's great answer, the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364698(v=vs.85).aspx) posted by @rownage (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598366/1811525)) provides some more information about the difference:

> ### Strong wildcard (Plus Sign +)
>
> When the host element of a UrlPrefix consists of a single plus sign
>   (+), the UrlPrefix matches all possible host names in the context of
>   its scheme, port and relativeURI elements, and falls into the strong
>   wildcard category.
>
> A strong wildcard is useful when an application needs to serve
>   requests addressed to one or more relativeURIs, regardless of how
>   those requests arrive on the machine or what site they specify in
>   their Host headers. Use of a strong wildcard in this situation avoids
>   the need to specify an exhaustive list of host and/or IP-addresses.
>
> ### Weak wildcard (Asterisk *)
>
> When an asterisk (*) appears as the host
>   element, then the UrlPrefix falls into the weak wildcard category.
>   This kind of UrlPrefix matches any host name associated with the
>   specified scheme, port and relativeURI that has not already been
>   matched by a strong-wildcard, explicit, or IP-bound weak-wildcard
>   UrlPrefix.
>
> This host specification can be used as a **default catch-all** in some
>   circumstances, or can be used to **specify a large section of URL
>   namespace** without having to use many UrlPrefixes.