# What's the difference between the + and * with HttpListener

Tags: c#, endpoint, httplistener

I want to implement a HttpListener that listen to a specific port, but i don't understand why i should use:

> -http://+:8080/ 
> or
>   -http://*:8080/ 
> or
>   -http://127.0.0.1:8080/   <->  http:// localhost:8080

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459679/623546) is a good answer for what you are asking
 essentially :

> https://*:8080: Receieve all https requests on port 8080 that are not
>   already being handled by some other HTTPListener
>
> https ://+:8080: Receive all https requests on port 8080 even if
>   they're already handled by another HTTPListener

.